# jQuery: clear a web form when the user clicks elsewhere

Tags: jquery, blur

I have a web page with 3 web forms, where the first two expect digital input and the last one may not be empty.

[image: A web form showing three text fields, two of them containing invalid inputs]

Here is the reduced and ready-to-run test case:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.invalid {
        border: 2px solid #FF0000;
        background-color: #FFCCCC;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        //$('body').click(....)
        $('#cl_txt, #mks_txt, #comment_txt').blur(function() {
           $('#cl_txt, #mks_txt, #comment_txt').removeClass('invalid');
        });

        $('#mks_btn').click(function(e) {
            if (! $('#mks_txt').val().match(/^[0-9]{6,}$/i)) {
                $('#mks_txt').addClass('invalid');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $('#cl_btn').click(function(e) {
            if (! $('#cl_txt').val().match(/^[0-9]{6,}$/i)) {
                $('#cl_txt').addClass('invalid');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $('#comment_btn').click(function(e) {
            if ($('#comment_txt').val().length < 2) {
                 $('#comment_txt').addClass('invalid');
                 e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
<form><tr><th>MKS</th><td>
<input name="toggle_mks" id="mks_txt" type="text" size="10">
<input type="submit" id="mks_btn" value="Add MKS" class="toggle">
</td></tr>
<form><tr><th>CL</th><td>
<input name="toggle_cl" id="cl_txt" type="text" size="10">
<input type="submit" id="cl_btn" value="Add CL" class="toggle">
</td></tr></form>
<form><tr><th>Comments</th><td>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment_txt" rows="4" cols="40">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" id="comment_btn" value="Add comment" class="toggle">
</td></tr></form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When invalid text has been entered and the corresponding submit button clicked, then I add the **.invalid** class to that text field or text area to make it appear red.

My problem is in handling situations, where the user changes her mind and decides not to submit that web form again. Instead she clicks into another web form or maybe just clicks somewhere in the web page.

In that case I would like the red **.invalid** class to be removed from the text elements **#cl_txt**, **#mks_txt** and **#comment_txt** again. But I don't know how to arrange it. I've tried setting **$('#cl_txt, #mks_txt, #comment_txt').blur(....)** but it never works consistently. I've tried **$('body').click(....)** instead, but then form validation seems to break, the text fields are never painted red.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [jQuery outside events](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/) plugin. Also, see the [demo](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-outside-events/examples/clickoutside/).
The main idea is that you delegate to element a `clickoutside` (or even `dblclickoutside`) event and specify what should happen when it fires.

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting information, but I'd preferred not to introduce yet another plugin. Maybe I could use a timeout somehow here - to un-red the fields after some time if none of them is focussed?

Comment: Of course, you can, but I think it would be "unnatural" here.